# Angular code keeps giving error when using http post

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass in a Person object I made in the client side of my code to a server using asp.net, but every time I run it, it returns a "server side error" even though it works fine in postman.

This is my component code:

```
this.proServ.addProfile(person).subscribe(
      (p: Person) => {
        console.log(p);
        this.reg = 3;
      },
      (error: any) => {console.log(error);} 
    );
```

This is my service code:

```
addProfile(person: Person): Observable<Person>{
    return this.http.post<Person>(this.API, person, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    })
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

And my API code: (just want to pass it in for now)

```
[HttpPost]
    public void AddPerson( Person person)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Adding Person: " + person.ToString());
    }
```

I am using the HttpClientModule

Comment: if it's saying server side error then there's an error on your server.  postman must be sending something different than angular and your server isn't handling it correctly. Probably want to use the network tab in your dev tools to inspect and compare the requests.

Comment: what is the http status code you are receiving?

Comment: I was looking at the network tab, and there aren't any post requests at all. I think it might have to do with CORS. I downloaded an extension to bypass it so maybe that's why. But I also added some code to my web.config in my API and it still didn't work.